# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'display' in databricks

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

In the Databricks [visualization reference](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html) it states

> PySpark, pandas, and koalas DataFrames have a display method that calls the Databricks display function. You can call it after a simple DataFrame operation

with example

```
diamonds_df = spark.read.csv("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
diamonds_df.select("color","price").display()
```

but when I try the same in my databricks cluster I get the error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'display'

Need help why I am gettin the error, I did all the same mentioned in the visulaization reference.

Comment: Are you trying this one on the Databricks notebook?

Comment: or `.display()` will work only for `Available in Databricks Runtime 7.1 and above.`

Comment: Okay, saw that but didn't knew I was using  default databricks runtime 6.5. Thanks @Lamanus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of Databricks Runtime version which was not supported, as mentioned by @[lamanus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11841571/lamanus)

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation:

```
display(diamonds_df.select("color","price"))
```

Comment: I know this works, I wanted to know why did above code gave error which I found out that it was because of Databricks runtime version. Hence not accepting the answer